# DataTable select rows where debit and credits match

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable

Where a DataTable has the following Columns

Account Number (Integer) (Unique)

Debit (Decimal)

Credit (Decimal)

Selected (Boolean)

There may be several rows with the same account number and either a Debit Entry or a Credit Entry. What I am attempting to do is match up the debits and credits where they add up to the same value and mark them as selected by iterating through all the rows. Any idea on the best method to achieve this?

Thanks

e.g.

[image: DateTable (in WPF DataGrid)]

SQL

```
strSQL = "SELECT A_Sales_Ledger.Transaction_ID as 'Transaction', "
        strSQL += "Customers.Cust_No as 'Acct', "
        strSQL += "Customers.Cust_Name as 'Name', "
        strSQL += "Customers.Add1 as 'Unit', "
        strSQL += "A_Sales_Ledger.Debit as 'Debit', "
        strSQL += "A_Sales_Ledger.Credit as 'Credit', "
        strSQL += "A_Sales_Ledger.Document_Date as 'Date', "
        strSQL += "A_Sales_Ledger.S_Description as 'Description' "
        strSQL += "FROM A_Sales_Ledger "
        strSQL += "JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customer_ID = A_Sales_Ledger.Customer_ID "
        strSQL += "WHERE A_Sales_Ledger.Paid = 'N' "
        strSQL += "ORDER BY Customers.Cust_No"
```

Comment: Have you tried using a linq query to join the table to itself on account # and where credit equals debit

Comment: Hey Conrad - Can you post an example? I don't have a problem where all the rows for the account number match i.e. SUM(Credit) = SUM(Debit).. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but it does seem to work...

I'm making three passes though the DataTable

Pass one - if the total of the debits equals the total of the credits for each customer mark them as selected

Pass two - Add the total of the credits for the customer and iterate though the debits until the same value is achieved and mark them as selected

Pass three - mop up any remaining credit entries that match a debit entry for the same customer...

```
             For Each Row As DataRow In BalanceDT.Rows
            Dim vAcct As String = Row("Acct")
            Dim vDebits As Decimal = BalanceDT.Compute("SUM(Debit)", "Acct = '" & vAcct & "'")
            Dim vCredits As Decimal = BalanceDT.Compute("SUM(Credit)", "Acct = '" & vAcct & "'")
            If vDebits = vCredits Then
                Row("Selected") = True
            End If
        Next


                    Dim CurrentCust As String = ""
        Dim TransactionDT As New DataTable
        Dim ExitFor As Boolean = False
        With TransactionDT.Columns
            .Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
        End With
        For Each Row As DataRow In BalanceDT.Rows
            Dim vAcct As String = Row("Acct")
            ExitFor = False
            TransactionDT.Rows.Clear()
            If Not CurrentCust = vAcct Then
                Dim vCredits As Decimal = BalanceDT.Compute("SUM(Credit)", "Acct = '" & vAcct & "'")
                Dim vSelected() As DataRow = BalanceDT.Select("Acct = '" & vAcct & "'", Nothing)
                For Each SubRow As DataRow In vSelected
                    If SubRow("Selected") = False Then
                        vCredits -= SubRow("Debit")
                        With TransactionDT.Rows
                            .Add(SubRow("Transaction"))
                        End With
                        If vCredits = 0 Then
                            ExitFor = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                If ExitFor = True Then
                    For Each SubRow As DataRow In vSelected
                        If SubRow("Credit") > 0 Then
                            SubRow("Selected") = True
                        End If
                        If SubRow("Debit") > 0 Then
                            For Each CustomerRow As DataRow In TransactionDT.Rows
                                If CustomerRow("ID") = SubRow("Transaction") Then
                                    SubRow("Selected") = True
                                End If
                            Next
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
            CurrentCust = vAcct
        Next

                    For Each Row As DataRow In BalanceDT.Rows
            Dim vAcct As String = Row("Acct")
            If Not CurrentCust = vAcct Then
                Dim vSelected() As DataRow = BalanceDT.Select("Acct = '" & vAcct & "' AND Selected = 'False'", "Credit")
                For Each SubRow As DataRow In vSelected
                    If SubRow("Selected") = False Then
                        Dim vCredit As Decimal = SubRow("Credit")
                        For Each CustomerRow In vSelected
                            If CustomerRow("Selected") = False Then
                                Dim vDebit As Decimal = CustomerRow("Debit")
                                If Not vDebit = 0 And Not vCredit = 0 Then
                                    If vDebit = vCredit Then
                                        With TransactionDT.Rows
                                            CustomerRow("Selected") = True
                                            SubRow("Selected") = True
                                        End With
                                        Exit For
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            CurrentCust = vAcct
        Next
```